# Understanding the error 'Is a macro, not a function'

Tags: macros, common-lisp, sbcl, file-compilation

I have had this error a few times `is a macro, not a function`. but found it hard to replicate the cause.

I have since discovered that the reason why I see the error is because I define a macro in a file I use it. And I use the macro above the definition.

**For example:**

In sbcl, i created a function for interactive interrupt from a terminal.

```lisp
(defun some-long-running-thread ()
  
  ...

  #+sbcl
  (sb-sys:interactive-interrupt ()
    (progn
      (color :red (princ "C-c was pressed")) ;; <-- my macro
      (uiop:quit))))

(defmacro color (color &body body)
  `(multiple-value-bind (col val)
     (cl-ansi-text:with-color (,color)
       (progn
         ,@body))
     (declare (ignore col))
     val))
```

What is actually happening behind the scenes whereby functions can be defined in any order but macros cannot?

Note: I often define macros in the same file I use them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A macro does source transformations during compile time.**

Say, you want to use a macro `foo` in your source code.

Say, your code first uses `(foo 123)`. Here the compiler does not know what `foo` is. The compiler assumes that it is a function. Thus it creates code for a function call to a yet unknown function `foo`.

Now you define a macro under the same name `foo`.
This has effects:

- the compiler has before assumed that `foo` is a function. Now you define it as a macro -> thus the warning.
- the compiler has already compiled code with the `foo` operator, as a function call. -> it won't recompile it.

**Rules, when introducing macros**

**a) define all macros before they are used in the source**

**b) provide all functionality (functions, macros, ...) which are used by the macro, before the macro is used in the source.**

The macro definition will be needed by the file compiler, when it sees a usage in that file: the macro will be needed to macroexpand the code during compile time.

**Practical: compiling functions vs. macros in a file**

Define a macro first before the function which might use the macro.

The file compiler (-> `compile-file`) treats function and macro definitions different:

- a function definition will be compiled, but it will not be loaded into the *compile time environment*. Thus during *file compilation* of a file, by default any function defined will not be callable during compilation.
- a macro definition will be compile **and** it will be loaded into the *compile time environment*. Thus a macro defined in a file, which is being compiled, can be expanded during compilation of that file.

Answer (score 1):

Functions can be defined in any order because when you call a function, it will look up the function binding when the function is executed. It will work properly as long as the function is defined before it's called at run-time.

Macros, on the other hand, are expanded by the compiler/interpreter when it's compiling/interpreting the function that uses it. Therefore, it needs to know the macro definition when it's processing the user.

Theoretically the file compiler could make multiple passes, first compiling all the macros and then all the functions. But this breaks the desired consistency between the compiler and interpreter.

Or if a function contains a call to a name whose definition isn't known, processing that call could be deferred until the function is called, and then it could either be expanded as a macro or translated to a function call depending on how the name is defined. But this really complicates things, especially when a project spans multiple files. We'd like everything to be processed at compile time -- even though Common Lisp provides a run-time `COMPILE` function, we don't usually want that overhead at run time.

So macros have to be defined before they're used. Any unknown name will be assumed to be a function rather than a macro. And then when it tries to call it, and it turns out to be a macro, you get an error.